# how to select all checkboxes in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how to select all checkboxes in angular 6?

I'm trying to make a table with checkboxes but I cant set a checkbox that check true all checboxes in per page.
I want to check all checkboxes but it isn't working correctly.

**html**

```html
    <table id="myTable">
      <tbody >
            </tbody>
            <tbody >
              <tr >
                <th>
                  <input type=" checkbox" (change)="checkAll(this)">
        </th>
        <th>
          id
        </th>
        <th>
          fname
        </th>
       
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tbody *ngFor="let item of result" style="border:1px solid #D3D3D3">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="getCheckboxValues($event,item)" [checked]="check_true">
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.id }}
        </td>
        <td>
          {{ item.fname }}
        </td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**component.ts**

```
       getCheckboxValues(ev, data) {
    let obj = {
      "order": data
    }
    let selected_rows = [];

    if (ev.target.checked) {
      // Pushing the object into array
      this.newArray.push(obj);
    } else {
      let el = this.newArray.find(itm => itm.order === data);

      if (el)
        this.newArray.splice(this.newArray.indexOf(el), 1);
      if (this.newArray.length == 0) {
        this.newArray = [];
      }
    }

    if (this.newArray.lenght > 0) {
      for (let i in this.newArray) {
        selected_rows.push(this.newArray[i].order.bulkid);

        this.selected_rows = selected_rows;
      }
    }
  }

  checkAll(ele) {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if (ele.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(ele)
}
```

I'm trying to make a table with checkboxes but I cant set a checkbox that check true all checboxes in per page.
I want to check all checkboxes but it isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepared a small demo to show how this can be done using `ngModel` directive. Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lxjrdh

It uses `Array.every` to check if all are checked or not. If checked, it resets all otherwise checks all.

Comment: nice - i would have the button click set a true/false on a variable and than set all checkboxes to that variable. This allows the same button to toggle all checkboxes off if clicked again... eg: if you create a variable of allCheckBoxes and the button click set this.allCheckBoxes =!this.allCheckBoxes....... that would toggle the allCheckBoxes variable on each click... then you simply have  this.checkboxes.forEach(val => { val.checked = allCheckBoxes }); and all the checkboxes will be checked / unchecked according to the state of the allCheckBoxes variable

Comment: @gavgrif it is just a concept which can be changed according to the need.

Comment: @gavgrif I have updated the solution to uncheck all if all are checked. THe default behavior of all select checkbox

Comment: thanks for that - only issue is that this now has two iterations over the array - one to check if every checkbox is checked and then the second to alter  the checked state of each. Far simpler to do it the way i had in the comments. but as you say - just a concept that can be modified

Comment: ....export class AppComponent {
  allCheckboxes: boolean = false;

  checkboxes: any[] = [
    { name: 'cb1', value: 'cb1', checked: false },
    { name: 'cb2', value: 'cb2', checked: true },
    { name: 'cb3', value: 'cb3', checked: false },
    { name: 'cb4', value: 'cb4', checked: false },
    { name: 'cb5', value: 'cb5', checked: false },
  ]

  CheckAllOptions() {
    this.allCheckboxes = !this.allCheckboxes;
    this.checkboxes.forEach(val => { val.checked = this.allCheckboxes });
  }
}

Comment: this allows a simple toggle of all checkboxes on and off based on the click

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Angular 6 CheckBox Select/ Unselect All';
  masterSelected:boolean;
  checklist:any;
  checkedList:any;

  constructor(){
      this.masterSelected = false;
      this.checklist = [
        {id:1,value:'A',isSelected:false},
        {id:2,value:'B',isSelected:true},
        {id:3,value:'C',isSelected:true},
        {id:4,value:'D',isSelected:false},
        {id:5,value:'E',isSelected:false},
        {id:6,value:'F',isSelected:false},
        {id:7,value:'G',isSelected:false},
        {id:8,value:'H',isSelected:false}
      ];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. .form-control:focus {    color: var(--bs-body-color);   
    background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);    border-color: #86b7fe;
    input[type=checkbox] {   display: none; }
           input[type=checkbox] + label:before {   content: "\2714";   border:
     padding-bottom:    
       0.3em;   margin-right: 0.2em;   vertical-align: bottom;   color: transparent;   transition: .2s; }
           input[type=checkbox] + label:active:before {   transform: scale(0); }
           input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {   background-color:    MediumSeaGreen;   border-color: MediumSeaGreen;
    color: #fff; }
 2. List item
```